# Sort array by time object base on current time in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm having issue on sorting the array by time object based on the current time. The code works sometimes but sometimes it does not. What is the error in my code, or is there a better method for sorting?

```
const sortTimeFromNow = (timenow,array) => {  
    array.sort();
    let index = array.findIndex((s) => { 
      return s.day.sched[0].time.start > timenow;
    });
    index -= index && 1;
    return index ? [...array.slice(index), ...array.slice(0, index)] : array;
  };
```

The idea is to sort it like this:

Example Time

> const timenow = new Date() //sample  '09:45:33'

Array Schedules

```
const array = [
   {"t":"evtA","sched":[{"day":"TUE","time":{"start":"20:00:35","end":"21:30:39"},"allday":false}] },
   {"t":"evtB","sched":[{"day":"TUE","time":{"start":"06:00:59","end":"14:00:59"},"allday":false}] },
   {"t":"evtC","sched":[{"day":"TUE","time":{"start":"15:00:59","end":"16:00:21"},"allday":false}] },
   {"t":"evtD","sched":[{"day":"TUE","time":{"start":"14:00:59","end":"15:00:21"},"allday":false}] }
]
```

Call function

> const result = sortTimeFromNow(timenow,array)

Sample Result should be

```
//Example1 '09:45:33'
[ 
 {"t":"evtB","sched":[{"day":"TUE","time":{"start":"06:00:59","end":"14:00:59"},"allday":false}] },
 {"t":"evtD","sched":[{"day":"TUE","time":{"start":"14:00:59","end":"15:00:21"},"allday":false}] },
 {"t":"evtC","sched":[{"day":"TUE","time":{"start":"15:00:59","end":"16:00:21"},"allday":false}] }, 
 {"t":"evtA","sched":[{"day":"TUE","time":{"start":"20:00:35","end":"21:30:39"},"allday":false}] },
]

//Example2 '15:01:00'
[ 
 {"t":"evtC","sched":[{"day":"TUE","time":{"start":"15:00:59","end":"16:00:21"},"allday":false}] }, 
 {"t":"evtA","sched":[{"day":"TUE","time":{"start":"20:00:35","end":"21:30:39"},"allday":false}] },
 {"t":"evtB","sched":[{"day":"TUE","time":{"start":"06:00:59","end":"14:00:59"},"allday":false}] },
 {"t":"evtD","sched":[{"day":"TUE","time":{"start":"14:00:59","end":"15:00:21"},"allday":false}] },
]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123953/how-to-sort-an-object-array-by-date-property

Comment: @JohnTyner that is not base on given time or current time

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely sort using a comparator function. Something like

```
function sortArray(array) {
  myArray.sort( function(x, y) {
     if(x.date.toISOString().split('T')[1] === y.date.toISOString().split('T')[1] ) {
    return 0;
   } else {
   return x.date.toISOString().split('T')[1] < y.date.toISOString().split('T')[1] ? 1 : -1
   }
  });
}
```

This case is a little basic, it's assuming you have dates or could create date objects out of your strings. In your case I would do something like

```
if(Date.now().toISOString().substring(11, 19) < x.time.start) {
 return -1
} else {
// do a normal comparison similar to above, since you know the date your comparing against is past the current time
}
```

Not a full solution but I hope the idea is there, best of luck!